# How can I get in touch with the Stack Overflow sales team for Talent?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-talent, contact-form, stack-exchange-team

I need to get in touch with the sales team for help with accessing the Talent product.

The web form is a dead end. Can someone give me contact of a sales rep to whom I can reach out directly and/or tell me if there is some other way to fast-track my request?

Comment: have reached out via my company email : priyank@apna.co

Comment: By dead end do you mean it doesnt work or you haven't gotten a response?

Comment: Did not get a response / auto response on email. Technically it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Please e-mail us at talent-support @ StackOverflow dot com. We'll get this sorted out for you.